# How to send alert for AWS EBS impaired volume?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-ebs, amazon-cloudwatch

What is the best method to send an alert via SNS for an AWS EBS volume that has been marked as "impaired"?

Within Console > EC2, under Instances > Status Check tab, you can set a CloudWatch alert.

However, there is no ability under the Volume > Status Check tab.

I discovered under Health Events there's a couple but they're only for "volume lost" and "degraded performance". Not exactly for an impaired volume.

The volume doesn't receive a lot of activity so monitoring any performance metrics likely isn't a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per AWS:

> Our engineers have stated that there is no volume metric in Amazon
>   CloudWatch. They have stated that you can create custom scripts to
>   describe the volume(s) every 5 minutes. You can then check the
>   returned status to see if it's impaired and take action based on the
>   result.
>
> You may also find this following documentation useful:
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-status.html

Answer (score 0):

According to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-volume-status.html#monitoring-volume-checks you can use CloudWatch Events to monitor EBS Volume status changes. You can then feed the Events into SNS topic of your choice or to a Lambda function or elsewhere to process the notification.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-cloud-watch-events.html -- I don't see an event for a volume flagged as being impaired.